# How can I plot a lot of columns of a data frame with ggplot with the same color?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
  Time f1            f2
  6.04 0.0030113949 -2.816807e-03
  6.05 0.0030217415 -2.830386e-03
  6.06 0.0030320970 -2.843984e-03
  6.07 0.0030424615 -2.857600e-03
  6.08 0.0030528349 -2.871233e-03
  6.09 0.0030632171 -2.884885e-03
  6.10 0.0030736081 -2.898555e-03
  6.11 0.0030840079 -2.912242e-03
```

I want to plot `f1` and `f2` with ggplot with the same color, and their average with a different color, all of them on the same plot.

What I did:

```
 df <- melt(df ,  id.vars = 'Time', variable.name = 'f')
ggplot(df, aes(Time,value)) + geom_line(aes(colour = f))
```

But It plots every evry columns with different colors.

Comment: Did you attempt anything? It's easier if you show the code you've tried and ask a specific question about where you are getting stuck. If you don't know where to begin, I suggest you google for a basic ggplot tutorial. We're not here just to write the code for you; we are here to help answer specific questions.

Comment: I did, and edited my post.

Comment: If you want everything the same color, don't specify `color` inside the `aes` but outside: use `color = 'grey'` instead off `aes(colour = f)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll take a shot.

```
install.packages('dplyr')
library(dplyr)
df <- mutate(df, f_mean = mean(f1 + f2))

ggplot(df, aes(x = Time, y = f1)) +
    geom_point(color = 'black') +
    geom_point(aes(x = Time, y = f2), color = 'black') +
    geom_point(aes(x = Time, y = f_mean), color = 'red')
```

You should be able to get to where you want to be with that code.  Also, take a look at the [ggplot2 cheat sheet](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/ggplot2-cheatsheet.pdf).

Comment: Those hardcoded `data$column` will break ggplot in all but the simplest cases. You should use `aes()`, and just specify the column names.

Comment: I further edited to move the constant colors outside of `aes()`. Best practice is to map data columns inside `aes()` but keep constants outside. Doesn't really make a difference for simple plots, but if there are facets or other complications this works reliably.

Comment: Thanks again, Gregor.  I use ggplot2 all the time, and this helps me.